# Question about eigenvalues of reflection operator matrix .

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Ok, so let's say we have a reflection operator that reflects across the arbitrary plane, and by that i mean $$ax+by+cz=0$$

where $$a,b,c$$ are real nubers such that at least one of them is not equal to zero.
Now, if i choose random plane, and i want to find matrix of reflection across that plane, and i want to find eigenvalues of that matrix is it true that eigenvalues would be 1 and -1, where 1 has algebraic multiplicity 2, and -1 has the algebraic multiplicity 1 no matter which plane i choose or which base i use to construct the matrix?

(NOTE: This is just my assumption based on previous experience with reflection operator matrices, for example, reflection across xy plane has diagonal matrix whose diagonal elements are 1, 1, -1 respectively when standard base is used, therefore, it has eigenvalues 1 and -1. I have no any proven evidence that this holds true in general, that's why i am wondering if this is true for every plane and every base choosen.)

Now, i am also wondering is there a standard way to determine base that gives me diagonal matrix as a representation of reflection operator, if not, how can i do that? And then of course, how can i switch between bases in order to find the matrix representation of given operator that is required?

Comment: [Householder transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Householder_transformation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any vector in the reflection plane will be mapped into itself, so the eigenvalue will be 1.  Such vectors span a space of dimension 2, so, yes, there are your two eigenvalues of 1.  Any vector lying on the line perpendicular to the plane and passing through the origin will be mapped into its own negative, so there is your eigenvalue of -1.  And, modulo an overall scaling factor, there is only one such vector, so there will be only one eigenvalue of -1.  So I think you are right.

You can find the type of base you are looking for by rotating your coordinates so that $z$ is normal to the reflection plane.  You can rotate your coordinates around that axis any way you like and you will get the diagonal matrix you are looking for.

One procedure for getting that rotation would be to first take the gradient of your expression

$\nabla(ax+by+cz) = a\hat{x}+b\hat{y}+c\hat{z}$

The gradient is always normal to the function, so you know that you have here the normal to the plane.  So take the vector $(a,b,c)$ and normalize it, and you have the vector normal to the plane.  Now, at this point, you just need any two other vectors that are normal to each other and also normal to this vector.  One way to get one would be to take this new vector, call it $\hat{w}$, and cross it with $\hat{x}$, $\hat{w}\times\hat{x}$ and normalize that to get a vector $\hat{v}$.  Then take $\hat{v}\times\hat{w}$ to get $\hat{u}$.  Your new basis is $\hat{u}, \hat{v}, \hat{w}$.  But you have to be prepared for the exception when $\hat{w}\times\hat{x} = 0$.

After you have your new vectors, you have to calculate 9 dot products to get the transformation matrix you need.  If you have a vector in $\hat{x}, \hat{y}, \hat{z}$ coordinates, say $(q,r,s)$, you transform it to the $\hat{u}, \hat{v}, \hat{w}$ basis by multiplying by

$\displaystyle
\left(\begin{array}& u\cdot x & u \cdot y & u \cdot z \\
v \cdot x  & v \cdot y & v \cdot z  \\
w \cdot x & w \cdot y & w \cdot z\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array} &q \\ r \\ s\end{array} \right)$

Comment: For the second part of your answer, is there a mathematical approach for rotating coordinates, i mean, how can i compute base that is required?

Comment: @cdummie  Please see my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks for help, but i was wondering if there is a way to do this using matrices? After all, i need to find the matrix representation of this operator

Comment: @cdumie Edited again.